# Comparing DSP vs DTSP

Tags: discussion

Everyone have theirs choice and comfort in learning through books and prefer one author(s) over another.

For concepts what is your preferred book and why?

- Digital Signal Processing - John G. Proakis & Dimitris K. Manolakis
- Discrete Time Signal Processing - Alan V. Oppenheim & Ronald W. Schafer

I did not learn from DTSP but DSP by Proakis et al is very nice.

Comment: This question has [sort-of been asked on the main site](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/427/what-resources-are-recommended-for-an-introduction-to-signal-processing-dsp/428#428).  Have a read through that question and see if yours is asking something different.

Comment: Indeed!!!

I may pick DTSP once I am done with DSP by Proakis et al.